# File Diff (over-under)

Tags: linux, diff, sublime-text

Is there a Linux software tool that will display diffs between two text files with a viewing option for "over-under"?

As an example Collab's over-under diff:
[image: Collab's over-under diff]
<sub>(source: [smartbear.com](http://images.smartbear.com/.a/6a010535ed641d970b0105368cca07970b-500wi))</sub>

A gui would be preferred, with the option to print out the diff and if it integrated with sublime, that would be excellent as well.